# How do I allow specific role to access the endpoint?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

Trying to restrict access to an endpoint only for users with the role "Manager".

when I open swagger, I use Login endpoint to login(it's successful) and then I try to run 'AddCategory' endpoint and response is 404.

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Manager")]
    [HttpPost("addCategory")]
    [SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.OK, type: null)]
    [SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)]
    [SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)]
    [SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)]
    public Category AddCategory([FromBody] Category category)
    {
        context.Categories.Add(category);
        context.SaveChanges();

        return category;
    }
```

Same happens if I do not log in. If I remove Authorize attribute, everything works fine.

I checked UserRoles table and user I'm logging in with is Manager. Also tried to put only [Authorize] attribute instead of role specific and still didn't work. In Swagger, Login endpoint returns 200 response but is there any other way to check if I'm logged in or not?

EDIT

This is how I Generate JwtToken on Login.

```
 var roleId = _appDbContext.UserRoles.Where(x => x.UserId == user.Id)
                .Select(x=>x.RoleId)
                .FirstOrDefault();

var role = _appDbContext.Roles.Where(x=>x.Id==roleId).FirstOrDefault();

var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
{
    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
    {
        new Claim("Id", user.Id),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, user.Email),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Email),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role.Name)
    }),
    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(30), // 5-10 
    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
};
```

Decoded token looks like this

```
"alg": "HS256",
"typ": "JWT"
}.{
  "Id": "3f4b1e8f-d15c-426e-9aa6-375ac53f27ae",
  "email": "manager@example.com",
  "sub": "manager@example.com",
  "jti": "6e1fb89e-5408-4c61-8258-8d2c7cead4ab",
  "role": "Manager",
  "nbf": 1658758635,
  "exp": 1658758665,
  "iat": 1658758635
}.[Signature]
```

However, I've never added anything in [AspNetRoleClaims] table. Should I add data to that table too?

EDIT :
This is Program.cs

```
var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("llvudfvkwvepwkdnsnwmuulyvtrawppf");

var tokenValidationParams = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
    ValidateIssuer = false,
    ValidateAudience = false,
    ValidateLifetime = true,
    RequireExpirationTime = false,
    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
};

builder.Services.AddSingleton(tokenValidationParams);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(jwt =>
{
    jwt.SaveToken = true;
    jwt.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParams;
});


builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Comment: @tixina3684 I checked UserRoles table and user I'm logging in with is Manager. Also tried to put only [Authorize] attribute instead of role specific and still didn't work. In Swagger, Login endpoint returns 200 response but is there any other way to check if I'm logged in or not?

Comment: Check the JWT authorisation header here https://jwt.ms .  It should contain a claim called roles with the value of manager.

Comment: @Neil thanks for advice. I'm manually adding ClaimTypes.Role in token. But I'm not adding anything in [AspNetRoleClaims] table. Already updated my question with relevant code

Comment: can you share authentication settings in program.cs

Comment: Have you added the policy in startup? You should have `.AddPolicyScheme()` after `.AddAuthentication()`.

Comment: @OkanKaradag updated the question, added code

Comment: @Neil I only have AddJwtBearer. Do I still need AddPolicyScheme?

Comment: Have you set token for swagger in program.cs? pls can you share it? and did you test the api in postman?

Comment: Maybe check the headers to see whether log in as manager or not.

Answer (score 0):

Add `app.UseAuthentication();` before `app.UseAuthorization();` in program.cs file

Comment: Didn't help. I think the problem is that I do not have any records in AspNetRoleClaims table. I'll have to add records to it

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.