# How to populate AspNetRoleClaims table?

Tags: .net, identityserver4, .net-6.0

I've added data to AspNetUsers and AspNetRoles tables.
However, I had a problem that [Authorize] attribute didn't recognize when I was logged in.
Asked question here([Link to old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73110289/how-do-i-allow-specific-role-to-access-the-endpoint/73113244#73113244)
and I think the reason behind my problem was that I have no data in AspNetRoleClaims table.
How do I add data there?

One way would be to add it trough migration but I don't know whether if it is a bad practice.

AppDbContext

```
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser, IdentityRole, string>
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<TestProject.Models.RefreshToken> RefreshTokens { get; set; }
}
```

Program.cs

```
var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("llvudfvkwvepwkdnsnwmuulyvtrawppf");

var tokenValidationParams = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
    ValidateIssuer = false,
    ValidateAudience = false,
    ValidateLifetime = true,
    RequireExpirationTime = false,
    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
};

builder.Services.AddSingleton(tokenValidationParams);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(jwt =>
{
    jwt.SaveToken = true;
    jwt.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParams;
});


builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
    
app.MapControllers();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.Run();
```

This test endpoint doesn't get entered after I log in

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Tokens")]
public IActionResult TestAuthorization()
{
    return Ok("You're Authorized");
}
```

This is the Login method that returns JWT token.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
[Route("Login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] UserLoginRequest user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
    var existingUser = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(user.Email);

    if (existingUser == null)
    {
        return BadRequest(new RegistrationResponse()
        {
            Errors = new List<string>() {
                    "Invalid login request"
                },
            Success = false
        });
    }

    var isCorrect = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(existingUser, user.Password);

    if (!isCorrect)
    {
        return BadRequest(new RegistrationResponse()
        {
            Errors = new List<string>() {
                    "Invalid login request"
                },
            Success = false
        });
    }

    var jwtToken = await GenerateJwtToken(existingUser);

    return Ok(jwtToken);
}

return BadRequest(new RegistrationResponse()
{
    Errors = new List<string>() {
            "Invalid payload"
        },
    Success = false
});
```

}

Answer (score 1):

One problem you have is the lack of **app.UseAuthentication();**

This statement must be added before   **app.UseAuthorization();**

So it becomes

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Without **UseAuthentication**, the **UseAuthorization** will not know who the user is.

A second thing is to add the following before UseAuthentication

```
app.UseRouting();
```

So that your pipeline looks like this:

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: I've added useAuthentication but problem is not solved. I'm still getting 404 error on an endpoint with [Authorize(Roles="Manager") attribute

Comment: see my updated answer, always make sure your routes and pages first work without any authorization, if you get 404, it is not due to the authentication/authorization sub-system.

Comment: I've updated Program.cs but it still doesn't work. I've updated my question with your code. Also added test endpoint to test whether if I was logged in or not. Turns out, I'm still not logged in

Comment: What HTTP Status code do you get back when you try to hit api/Tokens?
Your code provided in the question is an API, that receives JWT tokens from a client, why do you ahve builder.Services.AddIdentity(...) in the code? How do ou get the JWT token? 
Why do you provide your own key instead of letting JWTBearer get the key from IdentityServer?

Comment: I'm getting 404 when I hit api/tokens. If I remove builder.Services.AddIdentity(..), api/tokens gives 401 unauthorized response. And when I try to login, I get error saying "Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager". I'm storing users in local db, I guess that is why I need to have AddIdentity?

Comment: When you use AddJwtBearer, it does by default not need any relationship with Identity, instead, the received JWT token should preferably contain all the necessary claims/roles to let the user access the API. How do you get and send the JWT token? The Core purpose of addJwtBearer is to take the incoming JWT token and convert it to a ClaimsPrincipal User instance, that you then can pass through the authorization system.